# Single-Sign-On in Okta Dashboard by OIDC

Tags: spring, single-sign-on, openid-connect, okta

I am working on migrating legacy spring web application with SSO in Okta. My goal is the user goes to Okta domain and enters username and password. After Successful login to Okta domain, the user will redirect to Okta Dashboard which is set up a 'BookMark App' so the user can click the BookMark App and redirect to the default authentication path of legacy spring web application.

In this case, I want the legacy spring web application retrieve the Okta's User Info, such as name or custom attributes. I have tried a lot of solutions almost three weeks...

Can anyone suggest me some solutions on it?

*The spring version is 4.1.3.RELEASE, using JSP as FrontEnd. (Just Spring NOT SpringBoot)

I tried some Okta SDK like, Auth JS / Okta Java SDK / Okta-authn /Okta Spring but fails.

*** Updated at 29 Jan 2024 ***

I have upgraded the spring version to 5.0.0.RELEASE but still faces the following difficulties.

Single-Sign-On Flows:

1. Okta User goes to domain page (https://dev-XXXXXXX.okta.com) then entering username and password)
2. After successful login, the user redirect to Okta Dashboard and click the 'BookMark App' with uri ('http://localhost:8080/oktalogin")
3. The Spring web application's controller ("oktalogin") retrieve the Okta User's info, such as email, username or some custom claim's attribute.

I cannot do the STEP 3. so that the spring web application cannot retrieve the user information by the redirect link from BookMark App.
** I know BookMark app is a redirect link only but it seems attach some information via the link request. However, I don't know how to get and use these information. Many thanks.

Comment: You need to look into integrating your app with Okta for OIDC. Then you'll receive id token with information you are looking for. Google for guides, or use this one for starter https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-okta

Comment: **Spring 4.1.3 was released back in 2014**, you will hardly find anything (doc & libs) compatible with such a deprecated version. You should consider migrating to more recent versions of Spring before trying to integrate it with an OpenID Provider.

Comment: Thanks Philipp and ch4mp, I have already migrated the application from spring version 3 to 4. It seems that I have to migrate it again from 4 to 5...

Comment: And then 5 to 6. By the way, with recent version of Spring you don't have to use the Okta adapters (which are very Okta adherent). You can use just `spring-security-oauth2-client`. But **it will surely be easier if you use Boot**: `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client`, optionally with [this additional starter I wrote](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons): `spring-addons-starter-oidc` (which is compatible with any OpenID Provider)